# Why getting data with Entity Framwork is slow?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am creating a Windows forms program with C# and Entity Framework. I want to fetch data from SQL database and do some processing after fetching it.

Everything is good but the performance is too bad with too slow speed even with little data. My code is below and I want to know what is wrong with my code.

I searched a lot but nothing found helpful.

Thanks in advance

```
private readonly BarForooEntities1 _barforoosh = new BarForooEntities1();

public void Getdataforoosh()
{
    BindingSource b = new BindingSource();

    b.DataSource = (from m in _barforoosh.RadifsSendCenter
                    where m.Receive == false
                    select new
                           {
                               m.id_rec, m.Radifkolsal,
                               m.Dates, m.DateErsal,
                               m.TimeErsal, m.Karkhane,
                               m.Namekala, m.Vazn,
                               m.Bandal, m.Dobaskul,
                               m.OldYear, m.Sal,
                               m.del, m.edit, m.Daryaft,
                               m.Shobe, m.Greid, m.TedadBas, 
                               m.Rahgiry, m.Tozih, m.NoeShemsh, 
                               m.Metrazh, m.Keyfiat, m.Address,
                               m.City, m.Karbar, m.CodeKala,
                               m.CodeGoruh, m.CodeKG, m.CodeGreid,
                               m.Tel, m.ShenaseMeli, m.Sefaresh,
                               m.Tolid, m.Shenase, }).ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = b;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        int c = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

        var f = (from a in _barforoosh.RadifsSendCenter
                 where a.id_rec == c
                 select a).SingleOrDefault();
        f.Receive= true;
        _barforoosh.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: List most people you seem to assume using EF will magically make the database something you do not are about. In reality, though, you should care little about EF - instead you should work as with handwritten SQL: Table schemata, the generated SQL and the query plan are still needed. Because SQL does not magically disappear.

Comment: On top, some common sense helps. Your code is an awkward mis of EF and ancient technology, doing subselects in a row (what for) using a DataTable, not an OO approach. There is no performance analysis whatsoever from you (although a profiler is baseline analysis for a developer). Are we supposed to magically do your work for you?

Comment: I'm beginner in EF and I'm just learning it.

Comment: If you want get data why you updated it? Why you called SaveChanges inside for loop? You can call it once

Comment: "I'm beginner in EF and I'm just learning it" - this would be a good statement if you would behave like someone with a month of programming experience. You do not. Which means EF is not your problem, fundamental understanding is. Which means the statement is at minimum misleading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put `SaveChanges` method **outside of `for` loop**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
}
_barforoosh.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: what about the loop? i want edit a value in database after receiving them, i think my problem exactly is the loop that make the result too slow, but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Put SaveChanges outside of for loop

Comment: thanks man, the problem was the SaveChanges() inside of loop.